Integrating Hikvision Face Recognition Terminal (DS-K1T343) with Backend for Event-Based User Data Transmission
I'm working with the Hikvision DS-K1T343 Face Recognition Terminal (MinMoe Series) and need to set up an event system so that whenever a user completes a face check, the terminal will send user data to my backend server. The idea is to capture relevant user information (such as name, ID, or timestamp) and transmit it in real-time to trigger further backend processes.
Here's what I'm considering:

Event Configuration: Is it possible to configure the DS-K1T343 to generate an event after a successful face check?
Data Transmission: How can I program the terminal to send this data to my backend? (I'm considering using HTTP requests or a similar protocol if supported.)
SDK/API Use: Does Hikvision provide an SDK or API documentation that would allow me to achieve this kind of integration?
Alternative Solutions: Are there other methods or tools to receive real-time events from the terminal?

I'd appreciate any guidance on configuring the DS-K1T343 for real-time data transmission or advice from those who have set up similar integrations. Thanks!

Their documentation shows that there is a way to connect to the device via their mobile application, and it supports http... so I believe it would be possible to connect, use charles proxy or Wireshark and find out which calls are being made and then do any custom code you require
It seems there is a community helping out for this already https://github.com/pergolafabio/Hikvision-Addons

Create a TCP server listener.
On device under Alarm server settings, insert server IP and port.
Device will push all the events to that server, including user recognition and authentication results among all other events.
Parse json events and choose what you need.
Remember, if ANR option is enabled under alarm server. It is mandatory to send response to an event received with return 200 OK();
